# How do I use sharedPreferences with booleans?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

I am currently learning `sharedPreferences` and trying to set and get values to check if a button has been clicked or not.

This is my class for `sharedPreferences`

```
class UserSimplePrefences {
  static SharedPreferences? _preferences;
  static const _keyButton = 'buttonStatus';

  static Future init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static Future setButtonStatus(bool btnStatus) async {
    await _preferences?.setBool(_keyButton, btnStatus);
  }

  static bool? getButtonStatus() {
    return _preferences?.getBool(_keyButton);
  }
}
```

here in my main.dart
I have a button.

```
bool? onLineStatus;
//
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    onLineStatus = UserSimplePrefences.getButtonStatus() !;
    displayToastMessage(onLineStatus.toString(), context);
}

//
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//
RaisedButton(

    onPressed: () async {
        if (UserOnline! =true) {
        UserOnline = true;
        await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(true);
        displayToastMessage("You are Online now", context);
    } else {
        UserOnline =false;
        await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(false);
        displayToastMessage("You are Offline now", context);

    }}
),
}
```

`UserOnline`  is to toggle the button, works fine without `SharedPreferences`.
In more simple language, when I hit the button i.e `Online`  and close the app and reopen the app sometime later I want the `init` statement to be called with the toast message as `true` and similarly when I click `offline` I want the `init` statement to call the toast  `false`.

Issue: My toast message is always `true`.
`

Answer (score 0):

add setState to your onPressed

```
onPressed: () async {
        if (UserOnline! =true) {
        UserOnline = true;
        await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(true);
        displayToastMessage("You are Online now", context);
        setState(() {});
    } else {
        UserOnline =false;
        await UserSimplePrefences.setButtonStatus(false);
        displayToastMessage("You are Offline now", context);
        setState(() {});
    }}
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with `setState`